# TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlatformLocalStorage' of undefined

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, enzyme-to-snapshot

**I am running jest test on react-native  and getting this following errors**

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlatformLocalStorage' of undefined

  2 | import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
  3 | import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
> 4 | import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    | ^
  5 |
```

```
"dependencies":{
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "jest": "^24.1.0",
  "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.10.0",
},

  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup/test-setup.js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup/test-setup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules(?![\\/]rn-fetch-blob[\\/]|[\\/]react-native[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-config[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-navigation[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-status-bar-height[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-animatable[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-restart[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-linear-gradient[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-i18n[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-modal[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-smooth-pincode-input[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-swipe-gestures[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-root-toast[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-root-siblings[\\/]|[\\/]static-container[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-elements[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-ratings[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-progress[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-dialog[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-pdf[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-webview[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-check-box[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-share[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-haptic-feedback[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-responsive-screen[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view[\\/]|[\\/]he[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-iphone-x-helper[\\/]|[\\/]check-prop-types[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-image-progress[\\/]|[\\/]react-native-theming[\\/]|[\\/]@react-native-community/async-storage[\\/])/"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/(build|docs|node_modules)/",
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup"
    ],
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can some one please help me why this errors are coming when I run jest test in react-native app. i have updated several dev dependencies but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the AsyncStorage library. If, like me, you've ported from the `react-native` variant to the `react-native-community` one you may need to update your mocks (if you had them already).

```
jest.mock("@react-native-community/async-storage", () => {
   // a map/dict/kvs of types to return - the leaves of the def
   // are jest functions
   const apiMock = {
    getItem: jest.fn(() => {  // mock's AsyncStorage.getItem()
      return JSON.stringify("some mock data");
    }),
   };
   return apiMock;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to mock the Package.

1. In your project root directory, create
   `__mocks__/@react-native-async-storage directory`.
2. Inside that folder, create `async-storage.js` file.
3. Inside that file, export Async Storage mock.

```sh
export default from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock'
```

The full instruction is here https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest